# How do I resolve this “localhost unexpectedly closed the connection” error?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am working through "**Mean Machine: A beginner’s practical guide to the JavaScript stack**" by Chris Sevilleja. My problem is on page 60. Per the book's instructions, I have created a small `server.js` file, along with the `package.json`, and used `npm install` to create the `node_modules folder` and populate it with the appropriate modules. When I run 'server.js'. 
I received a message in the terminal running the `console.log()` message which I placed at the end of the program and hence I know the program executed.

But when I then go to Chrome and put '`https://localhost:8080`" in the search bar, I receive the following error message:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I have spent over an hour trying to figure this out and am pretty lost. If I use 'http' instead of 'https', it just takes forever to load (I waited for about 5 minutes). I have checked whether I have asynchronous DNS flag in Chrome or something and confirmed that it is enabled. I tried doing "$ lsof -i:8080" on the terminal and got:

> COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
>   node 6188 23u IPv6 0x3a96cd0448d7ba87 0t0 TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)

(Not really sure what it does but I saw it on a webpage addressing a similar problem and the responders instructed the person to do that.) I have tried accessing it on Safari as well and receive the same message.

My code is below:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set the port for our app

var app = express(); // define our app in terms of Express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);

// configure out app to handle CORS requests
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});

// log all requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// API routes

// basic route for the home page
// route, not middleware, so no 'next' parameter
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to the home page!');
});

// get an instance of the express router
var apiRouter = express.Router();

// test route to make sure everything is working
// accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api
apiRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({message: 'Welcome to our API.'});
});

// mount apiRouter on our app
// they will all be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// start the server on the port we indicated on line 6
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Any suggestions to get my 'res.send('Welcome to the home page!');' message to display would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance. I've tried to describe the problem as well as I can but if there is any other information you need please let me know.

Sort of a follow up: I'm using SublimeText. Is this problem something I could identify/solve using a more sophisticated IDE?

Comment: Did you see 'Magic happens on port 8080' on console?

Answer (score 4):

instead of "https://localhost:8080" put "http://localhost:8080" in the chrome. remove s.

Answer (score 2):

For me I thought the antivirus was blocking all the localhost. We started to notice this very recently, perhaps, after our IT guy had changed something on the filtering policy which caused the localhost to fail and chrome presented the error as `localhost unexpectedly closed the connection` and for firefox the error was `An error occurred during a connection to localhost:port. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR`.

Things we tested:

- We had temporarily paused the antivirus protection.
- Opened the same localhost sites in `incognito` mode:

  - This is important for a quick test to see if the antivirus is actually causing it.
  - You can clear the browser cache as well if you intend not to use incognito.
- Check if the HTTP sites are not using HTTPS:

  - When you paste an HTTP site url in chrome, sometimes it changes the HTTP to HTTPs in the URL for example if you have a site `http://localhost:port/something` and when you paste it in google chrome's address bar, it might change the HTTP to HTTPS in the url like `https://localhost:port/something` which again may cause a problem on the page.
    [image: Why is Chrome defaulting to HTTPS?]

PS: We were using `kaspersky` antivirus.

---

After a little time, now I feel it is only because the Google Chrome is changing the http calls to https silently and has nothing to do with antivirus. It happened with the latest release of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

My project was dockerized and I was using gunicorn.

Previous command:

```
gunicorn config.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

New command:

```
python3 /<your_project>/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```